# What is the best way to handle response from Alamofire for a TableView in Swift using separate classes?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofire

I'm writing a class to handle my server requests that return JSON to populate a TableView. This is my first time doing this sort of thing, and I was curious what is the be best paradigm to use here. Is something like delegation better than using dispatch_async? Pretty much Alamofire's response is asynchronous, so I can't return data out of it. Since my request is happening in a shared(it exists in a framework I created so I could use it in multiple targets) ServerManager class, I need to get it to the TableView some how, and I'm not sure what the best way to do that.

What are the pros of delegation over background threading and vice versa? I know this question probably gets asked a lot around here, but I couldn't seem to find a good explanation when I was searching.

Comment: You normally use both, delegation on a single thread does not get you very far, you use background threads for the requests and delegation to communicate the returned data to the actual requestor.

Comment: Only because I'm not too familiar with dispatch_async, how does your receiving class know when to check? Meaning, I make my request, get my JSON response, how does my tableview know it has to check for new data?

Comment: That is completely up to you, use a timer that checks every 10 seconds, or when the user pulls down or if some refresh button is pressed.

Comment: The way I usually do it is set an array property on the class such as `var items = [Items]()` setup the table as usual, so when the view loads there's no data. Then in my requests completionHandler (after parsing) I'll do something like `items = response['results'] as! [Items]` then `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: @Scriptable That's assuming your request and your tableview are in the same class though right?

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks, I'll have to look into how to do dispatch_async, and how to structure my tableview better so that it can update properly. Never done this before, so new territory!

Comment: not really, I usually have an APIClient class which handles the requests, this is in its own class, in the VC in which I want to use it such as this one with a table I'll make a call like `APIClient.get('api/content', params) { (response, error) in items = response['items'] as! [Items]; self.tableView.reloadData() }` (wrapped in a dispatch async call to update UI). Here's an example: https://github.com/martinjkelly/On-The-Map/blob/master/On%20The%20Map/TableViewController.swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method in `ServerManager` should be passed a closure (block). This requires no delegation and no dispatches in the view controller.

```
class ServerManager {
    func fetchObjectsWithOptions(options: [AnyObject], completion: (items: [AnyObject], error: ErrorType?) -> Void) {
        // Use the options to setup and make the request
        // Be sure it executes on the main thread
        completion(items: items, error: nil)
        // Any finishing needed
    }
}

// ...

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    lazy var serverManager = ServerManager()
    var items: [AnyObject] = []

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        serverManager.fetchObjectsWithOptions([]) {
            items, error in

            if error == nil {
                self.items = items
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

Closures are functions which can be assigned to a variables. Closures are relatively simple in Swift. Here is a closure that takes no parameters and has a void return type.

```
{ () -> Void in print("foo") }
```

Below, the variable `x` has the type signature of `() -> Void`, and is assigned the closure. Executing the closure is done just line calling a function, `x()`.

```
let x: () -> Void = { () -> Void in print("foo") }
x() // prints foo
```

Closures can be passed around as function parameters. When `funcWithClosure()` is called, it executes the closure.

```
func funcWithClosure(x: () -> Void) {
    x()
}

funcWithClosure({ () -> Void in print("foo") })
```

Closures which take parameters have the parameters and their types specified as part of the closure type.

```
func funcWithClosure2(x: (string: String) -> Void) {
    x(string: "foo") // <-- parameters must be named
}

funcWithClosure2({ (string: String) -> Void in print(string) })
```

The type inference engine allows you to remove the type from the closure.

```
funcWithClosure({ print("foo") }) // <-- No type declaration
funcWithClosure2({ string in print(string) }) // <-- Only parameter name
```

In addition, if a closure is the last parameter, you don't need the parentheses around the closure.

```
funcWithClosure { print("foo") }
```

Finally, here is an example with multiple parameter ending with a closure.

```
func funcWithString(string: String, closure: (string: String) -> Void) {
    closure(string: string)
}

funcWithString("foo", closure: { (string: String) -> Void in print(string) })
```

Or, you can use the less verbose syntax.

```
funcWithString("foo") { string in print(string) }
```

Comment: I've never used closures before, would you mind explaining a little more how this works? I see that fetchObjectsWithOptions takes options, which we may or may not use, and then a parameter called `completion` which is of type function that takes `items` and an error if any, and returns nothing. But at the end of the function you call completion. Why is that?

Comment: Be mindful if you ever need to store closures as strong references, use a capture list to avoid retain cycles. More info: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID56

Comment: Why do you have to put `lazy` keyword on ServerManager variable?

Comment: @TomSawyer you don't. I lazy load things like manager instances. Sometimes the manger is never used. Sometimes the manager is reassigned.