# Swift: Lazy load variable vs MVC model?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, lazy-loading

I'm building an app with MVC Model.
I use lazy load technical to fill up a variable. (Model)
And this variable is being by one UIViewController (Controller)

But i don't know how to reload or trigger the view controller when the model action is finished. Here is my code

Model (lazy load data)

```
class func allQuotes() -> [IndexQuotes]
    {
        var quotes = [IndexQuotes]()
        Alamofire.request(.GET, api_indexquotes).responseJSON { response in
            if response.result.isSuccess && response.result.value != nil {
                for i in (response.result.value as! [AnyObject]) {
                    let photo = IndexQuotes(dictionary: i as! NSDictionary)
                    quotes.append(photo)
                }

            }
        }

        return quotes
    }
```

And the part of view controller

class Index:

```
UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var quotes = IndexQuotes.allQuotes()
    var collectionView:UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
```

This is really serious question, i'm confusing what technic will be used to full fill my purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Alamofire` works asynchronously you need a completion block to return the data after being received

```
  class func allQuotes(completion: ([IndexQuotes]) -> Void)
  {
    var quotes = [IndexQuotes]()
    Alamofire.request(.GET, api_indexquotes).responseJSON { response in
      if response.result.isSuccess && response.result.value != nil {
        for photoDict in (response.result.value as! [NSDictionary]) {
          let photo = IndexQuotes(dictionary: photoDict)
          quotes.append(photo)
        }
      }
      completion(quotes)
    }
  }
```

Or a bit "Swiftier"

```
... {
   let allPhotos = response.result.value as! [NSDictionary]
   quotes = allPhotos.map {IndexQuotes(dictionary: $0)}
}
```

I'd recommend also to use native Swift collection types rather than `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`

In `viewDidLoad` in your view controller call `allQuotes` and reload the table view in the completion block on the main thread.

The `indexQuotes` property starting with a lowercase letter is assumed to be the data source array of the table view

```
var indexQuotes = [IndexQuotes]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  IndexQuotes.allQuotes { (quotes) in
    self.indexQuotes = quotes
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, i've test. It works. Thanks. I've been reseaching about closure and completion and i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548180/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-response-from-alamofire-for-a-tableview-in-swift . I think this is the similar way to your solution, but they use `lazy` keyword before the variable. Do you know why?

Comment: In your mentioned topic a lazy variable is used to create an instance of a class. Here you're using a class function which is quite different.

Comment: @TomSawyer The statement `self.indexQuotes = quotes` must be executed on the main thread, otherwise it's not "thread-safe"  ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's async action, just use a callback here:

```
class func allQuotes(callback: () -> Void) -> [IndexQuotes]
    {
        var quotes = [IndexQuotes]()
        Alamofire.request(.GET, api_indexquotes).responseJSON { response in
            if response.result.isSuccess && response.result.value != nil {
                for i in (response.result.value as! [AnyObject]) {
                    let photo = IndexQuotes(dictionary: i as! NSDictionary)
                    quotes.append(photo)
                }
            }

            callback()
        }

        return quotes
    }
```

In your UIViewController:

```
var quotes = IndexQuotes.allQuotes() {
    self.update()
}
var collectionView:UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    update()
}

private func update() {
    // Update collection view or whatever.
}
```

Actually, I strongly don't recommend to use class functions in this case (and many other cases too), it's not scalable and difficult to maintain after some time.

Comment: I've received this error: `Use of instance member 'update' on type 'Index'; did you mean to use a value of type 'Index' instead?`. Is this the completion block? After finish the `allQuotes` method, it will execute `callback()` ?

Comment: This does not work, because the `return quotes` line returns always an empty array. You need to return the populated array in the callback block

Answer (score 0):

First of all call the function from inside the viewdidLoad. Secondly use blocks or delegation to pass the control back to ViewController. I would prefer the blocks approch. You can have completion and failure blocks. In completions block you can reload the views and on failure you can use alertcontroller or do nothing.

You can see AFNetworking as an example for blocks.

Comment: Why i have to call function from inside of the `viewdidLoad` ? what is difference between declare variable outside of that method?

Comment: You actually have to use blocks or delegation as your method is async. If your method was straight forward returning a value that would have been working fine then.